# Did Shukracharya recite a mantra or did a ritual to ensure Yayati didn't incur the sin of begeting child from pratiloma marriage?

Tags: mahabharata, varnashrama, shukracharya

King Yayati was hesitant to marry Devayani as it would be a Pratiloma marriage. From [Sambhava Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01082.htm)

> Yayati, thereupon, replied, 'Beautiful one, I do not deserve thee. Thou art the daughter of Sukra far superior to me. Thy father cannot bestow thee even on a great king.'

He then adds

> 'O thou of the handsomest features, the four orders have, indeed, sprung from one body. But their duties and purity are not the same, the Brahmana being truly superior to all.'

And says will only marry her if her father, Shukracharya, permits. Shukracharya was fine with the marriage and gave a boon to Yayati

> Sukra exclaimed, 'O thou of splendid courage, thou hast, indeed, been accepted as her lord by this my dear daughter. I bestow her on thee. Therefore, O son of Nahusha, accept her as thy wife.'

> "Yayati then said, 'I solicit the boon, O Brahmana, that by so doing, the sin of begetting a half-breed might not touch me.' Sukra, however, assured him by saying, 'I shall absolve thee from the sin. Ask thou the boon that thou desirest. Fear not to wed her. I grant thee absolution.

My question is can such a boon be granted so easily?  In Mahabharata itself we have story of Rsi Matanga  who despite austerities failed to become Brahmin. So how is it possible in the case of Yayati?

Comment: First, Yayati did not become a brahmin. The boon was that Shukracharya would expend lot of tapo-balam to ensure the Pratiloma marriage would not be counted negatively towards Yayati. It's a bit like a private deal with income-tax authorities to pay fine instead of full amount. Second, it was not granted 'easily' - Devayani, his doted daughter, deeply insisted on marrying him. Also, Devayani was cursed by Kacha to not have a brahmin husband, so it was a pre-destined match. Later Yayati went on to marry kshatriya lady who was Devayani's friend-turned-slave, for which Shukracharya cursed Yayati

Comment: @mar - Thanks. Do you have any reference to Shukracharya expending his tapo-balam in  lieu of such a boon. That can then be incorporated in the answer

Comment: i only heard it in upanyasam. no english translation online 1. is a full translation from sanskrit 2.does justice to intent of kavi. upanyasams of scholars who study vedas and learned granthas from feet of their acharyas are true repository of sukshma details. pravachanam.com is a great resource in many regional languages